# Chessjs cannot be imported without using es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, chess

In all of the chessjs documentation, `const chess = require('chess');` is used.

However, when I try to use this syntax, I get this error:

```
const Chess = require('chess');
              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module is not supported.
Instead change the require of main.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You may follow the steps defined here for the solution:  https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c#how-can-i-move-my-commonjs-project-to-esm

Comment: @kavigun the problem is that I cannot migrate the entire project to ESM. I `require` some modules depending on an if statement in the middle of my index file, which you can't do with esm because `import`s have to be top-level only.

Comment: You can use `await import()` for those inline cases

Comment: That is also the syntax you need if you want to import a `ESM` module in a CJS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dynamic import()` looks like this

```
async function loader(){
  const Chess = await import('chess')
  // things with Chess
}
```

As Evert mentioned, this can also cover the conditional import in an ESModule

Comment: I never knew this existed in common js. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the solution to the general question (which is why I'm not marking this as the solution), I ended up just migrating away from the module `chess` which doesn't allow commonjs requires to the module `chess.js` which allows both.

New code:

```js
const { Chess }= require('chess.js');
```